# How to upsample voice properly?

Tags: audio, sampling, resampling, upsampling, supersampling

I have a low quality `24 kHz` mp3 voice and I'd like to upsample it to `48 kHz` for farther mixing with another `48 kHz` track.

What is the right steepness curve in this case? I'm going to use [an ideal low-pass filter](https://s3.amazonaws.com/izotopedownloads/docs/rx8/en/resample/index.html) with:

```
Filter steepness=2000
Cutoff shift=1
Pre-ringing=1
```

but I'm not sure if that would create noise/artifacts or degrade the signal?

[image]

Upsample with steep curve:
[image]

Reduced steepness:
[image]

Low steepness creates artefacts.

Answer (score 1):

It barely matters – speech has no significant content close to 12 kHz, so using a relaxed filter works. Reduce the filter steepness a lot; as long as things up to 6 kHz pass through, you won't hear a difference.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why an ideal low-pass filter (with maximum steepness) is bad in this case? I'm trying to save as much information as possible. What `Pre-ringing` is better?

Comment: there's no such thing as an ideal low-pass filter – just very steep filters that necessarily become very long filters. And these come with problems such as strong phase distortion and numerical instability (at least in the IIR case), they are computationally undesirable (read: much CPU) and have no *positive* effect if there's nothing close to the Nyquist frequency to suppress as in your case.

Comment: They call it `ideal low-pass filter` in the docs: https://s3.amazonaws.com/izotopedownloads/docs/rx8/en/resample/index.html
I updated the post.

Comment: they lie. An ideal low-pass filter **cannot** exist, mathematically.

Comment: I reduced the filter steepness a lot as you suggested. Some artefacts appeared above 12 kHz (see the last image).

Comment: I would play around with it until you have something you think is good enough. You don’t need to completely cut out everything above 12 kHz, you just need to attenuate it enough so you don’t hear the effects of aliasing. Listening to it may be more fruitful than just looking at a spectrogram.

Comment: I came here to see exact answer, not idle speculation.

Comment: @dereks phrasing... you're the one asking here, so please be patient with the people trying to help you! And nothing about what Ryan nor I wrote was speculation. *you're* the one that believes there's implementations of ideal filters...

Comment: The question is "What is the right steepness curve in this case?". I ask  about these 3 options: `Filter steepness=?, Cutoff shift=?, Pre-ringing=?` If you don't know the answer, just don't write anything.

Comment: @dereks again, we're not your personal workforce; we try to help you understand what you're doing to enable you to solve your next problem yourself. My answer was meant to answer your question (it actually does! It says how you should change your parametrization), and if you don't understand it, you'd be more than welcome to ask for clarification, but honestly, my enthusiasm for helping you wanes in the face of your attitude.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You write: `Reduce the filter steepness a lot; as long as things up to 6 kHz pass through`. The result of this is the screenshot at the end of my post. If you think this is normal, then I have great doubts that you understand what you are writing about. You write what you know, not what I ask. Let the community determine the value of your answer. I suggest you end this conversation.

Comment: @dereks honestly, with you being hostile I don't care about your problem anymore. Have a nice day.